# CLion Out of Memory Issues

Tags: clion

I ran a simple `CLion` project with only two directories which each contain a single file. However, I was getting this message `“Out of Memory”`. I increased the `Xmx from 2GB to 4GB`. I believe this is more than enough. How can I fix this problem?

This is the settings in the `clion64.exe.vmoptions` file:

```
   -Xss2m
   -Xms256m 

   -Xmx4000m

   -XX:MaxPermSize=350m

   -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m

   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

   -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

   -ea

   -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false

   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 1):

try there settings:

-Xss2m

-Xms256m

-Xmx2000m

-XX:NewSize=128m

-XX:MaxNewSize=128m

-XX:MaxPermSize=350m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m

-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC

-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50

-ea

-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

refer to this page for more info: 
[link](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827537-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties)

Comment: Those are pretty same setting, except: **-Xmx2000m

-XX:NewSize=128m

-XX:MaxNewSize=128m**