# CLion uses system memory excessively

Tags: c, memory, ide, clion

I recently started to use CLion, on Windows 7 64-bit, for editing C files.

One thing that bothers me a lot is that it uses too much system memory. It doesn't cause *out of memory error* as asked in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30521729/clion-out-of-memory-issues). Actually CLion shows much lesser memory consumption in IDE (~500 mb out of ~2000 mb) than it takes from system (~1000 mb). You can see a snapshot of the system memory usage and CLion's memory display below:

[image]

I use CLion not for C++ but for C projects. My project isn't that big (~5 c files < 300 lines and ~10 h files). I don't use it to compile the project, I just use it for editing. And during the snapshot there was no user program running by it. And CLion wasn't showing any processes running (indexing etc). It is a general behaviour.

I'm not sure if what I experience is something expected/normal, or it is caused because of my system setup, project settings or the way I use the IDE.

Is there any known causes for excessive memory usage? Can you suggest practices to decrease memory usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post is 2 years old, but I am also having this issue with CLion 2018.1, and I imagine, others do, too. Some tips that worked for me:

- [Excluding directories from indexing](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2015/12/mark-dir-as/).
- Deleting source files I don't need.
- Resolving a circular dependency between two classes. (Note: I can't vouch it was exactly that, because I tried several things at once, and it seems odd that such a powerful IDE would be affected by such an issue, but I can't rule it out.)
- If it's really bad, the indexing can be paused. Guaranteed to reduce the memory usage. Of course, the intelligent completion won't work then.

Currently the RAM usage is stable at ~1 Gb with RocksDB, RapidJson, and ~50 classes.

UPDATE: tweaking `clion64.exe.vmoptions` reduced the consumption radically.

Comment: What `vmoptions` did you use to reduce memory usage?

Comment: Sorry, @M2X, that was over a year ago! Since then a new version emerged. From my very vague recollection, stack, mx, that sort of thing. But I can't vouch for that.

Comment: Thanks @Vadim Berman. Yeah, issue is every single version consumes a lot of memory. Those values you mentioned, I've tweaked in the past... Didn't make things much better

Comment: `-Xmx2048m` for me at least setting the max memory in custom vm option in CLion can use helped

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here. I haven't used CLion just sitting there so that I do not have to open again, 2 projects few files open, nothing major, still eating up +3GB is not something that I can accept, switching back to Sublime, that works fine, as others have mentioned I am using it only for editing/refactoring, compilation happens in Terminal.

(PyCharm has similar issues)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

CLion need to index and support all information about the system headers to provide you smart completion, auto-import and symbol resolution. Your project is the smallest part of code base for analyzing.

Comment: Thank you for information. Does it mean that my experience is expected behaviour? Do you experience similar or higher memory usage?

Comment: yes, it is. CLean is the only JB IDE, that has not 32bit version. Just because. ~16GB for WebKit or Unreal Engine is ok. Memory usage is uneven. The initial indexing is memory-expensive as well as data-flow analysis (finding unused code).

Comment: 1000mb for editing 5 files is actually unacceptable. I have the same issue and think I'll switch back to using VIM.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard about version 2020.3, which brings option to switch off refreshing files.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360007093580-How-to-disable-refreshing-files-after-build
Unfortunately I cannot try it out in my professional development environment.