# C++ loading 500MB of data with vector use 5GB of RAM

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, memory-leaks, ram

I am writing a code for sorting a Large chunk of strings (~ 2GB) and I am using a method similar to bucket sort. I have about 47000 vectors and each of them will have ~100 elements (char*) on average. (Due to input, some of them could have a lot of elements and some could be empty)

My code for getting input is something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
#define digitize(a) ((a>47 && a<58)*(a-48)+(a>96 && a<123)*(a-87)) //base 36 convert
int main(){
 int n = 0;
    scanf("%d\n", &n);

    vector<char *> buckets[46657]; // 36 *36 *36 = 46656




    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        char *temp = static_cast<char *>(calloc(255, sizeof(char)));
        scanf("%s\n", temp);
        int d1 = temp[0];
        int d2 = temp[1];
        int d3 = temp[2];

        int index = digitize(d1) * 1296 + digitize(d2) * 36 + digitize(d3); // 1296 = 36*36

        buckets[index].push_back(temp);

    }
}
```

digitize is actually a base 36 converter. (i.e. 0:0, 1:1 .... a:10, b:11, ... , z:36) Because my data consists of numbers and lowercase chars.

By running this code on a 500MB dataset (Which is randomly generated) the ram usage of the file goes above 4GB and near 5GB. (OS: Windows7 64bit, IDE: Jetbrains CLion, Compiler: G++)

Is it normal? I don't understand why it use these huge amount of ram just for getting data. I also checked the output by adding another loop and they were correct. So there is no infinite Loop or something like that. The code works fine but use a huge amount of RAM.

Any Idea why it uses this huge amount of RAM.

Comment: Why are you allocating 255 characters of space when you are only using 3 of them?

Comment: @NathanOliver They will be used later for sorting. As I said, it is only the input part of a very huge program. I commented all the parts out and found that its input part uses 5 GB of RAM. Each string of the input can be at most 254 chars long.

Comment: What's `n`, for this data set?

Comment: @hegel5000 count of strings that should be read from input.
for example input could be:
3
abb
bbb
ccc

(Actually the strings are much larger than just abb, the above is just an example)

Comment: Yes, but what is `n` for the data set you tested?  As in, in this particular test where you found that the program used ~4-5GB, what value was parsed in for `n`?

Comment: @hegel5000 about 2 Million. So 2 Million strings of 250 bytes is approximately 500MB.

Comment: @amirna how exactly are you measuring your memory usage?

Comment: @tangy With Task Manager. I know it is not very exact but I think it is improbable that it miss by about 5-10 times the real value.

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate it :(  I got the expected ~500MB in Linux, looking at it with htop

Comment: @amirna Possibly because CLion itself must be using memory for its background processes? eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497805/clion-uses-system-memory-excessively . Can you try running the process in a standalone way and measuring?

Comment: @tangy I also run it using only cmd command (main.exe < input.txt) and it was about 4 GB. (~1 GB less) So, Clion has some effect but not that much.

Comment: compiling with visual studio also only uses 650mb of memory, must be something strange with your version of gcc or you haven't supplied a [mre]

Comment: I tested it with Ubuntu and it worked fine by using about 750mb. I think there is some problem with my Windows 7 (I know Win7 is outdated but the code will be used for a program that must support Win7)

I believe my problem is unfortunately very difficult to reproduce :(

Comment: Prefer to use character literals, like `'0'`, instead of their ASCII encoding (0x30).  Makes your program a lot more readable.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for the advice. I will keep that in mind for future programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What makes you think that you consume 5Gb ?

You create an array of 46657 `vector<char*>`. Each vector has in average 100 `char*` pointing to a newly allocated string of 255 bytes.  That's at least `sizeof(buckets)+46657*100*(sizeof(char*)+255)` bytes. Depending on the implementation, this could be around 1.2 Gb.  The vectors may hold some space reserved for faster growth. But this will not change fundamentally our order of magnitude.

All this is huge, perhaps more than you need, but it's far from the 5Gb that you measure.  But what did you measure in the first place?

The memory consumption statistics that you provide are most probably managed at operating system level.  It's the memory consumed by the process executing your code, not necessarily the code that your code consumes.  All this is implementation dependent, but in general the standard library may allocate very big memory chunks from the OS, because calls to OS are more expensive than local calls in the user space.  This big chunk is then cut into pieces at each `new` or `malloc` call.  It's like a wholesaler and a retailer.

To know the memory that your code consume, you need to do more precise memory monitoring/profiling. For example you could use `valgrind` or other tools depending on your OS.

#### Avoiding leaks

We do not see the full code, so leaks are not excluded either.  Since you manually manage memroy, the risk of leaking is higher.  Not speaking of unsanitized scanning, which could exceed the 255 allocated chars and corrupt memory.

A safer approach could therefore be:

```
vector<string> buckets[46657]; 
...
for ...
    string temp; // let the string take care of its own memory
    getline(cin, temp);  
    ...
```

As a side effect, you also benefit from optimized memory management, if you have many smaller strings.